# Connection getting close immediately after establishing web-socket connection in python

Tags: python-3.x, websocket

I was trying to create a web-socket connection to a service.I am using the web-socket lib in python.So when I use that lib, I get a connection object and I am able to access URLs and headers from that conn object but when I try to send some random data (string) over that connection, it immediately closes the connection.

Code Snippet

```
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://" + websocket_url,header = headers_conn1)
```

ws.send("data)

As soon as I send this data it immediately throws me error "connection is closed"
Any suggestions on this?